# c++ #include macro names must be identifiers

Tags: c++, header

I'm making a C++ header file for learning purposes. It's supposed to give me the length of the number (be it an *int, float, double* etc.) without counting the comma. Here's my code:

```
#ifndef NUMLEN_H
#define NUMLEN_H
#define <cstring>

int numlen (char numberLengthSample[])  //numlen - lenghth of the number, numberLengthSample - the number you put in.
{
    int numberLengthDummy = strlen (numberLengthSample);    //a temporary int used in counting the length
int numlenc = strlen (numberLengthSample);  //the true length of the number
while (numberLengthDummy>0)
{
    if (numberLengthSample[numberLengthDummy-1]=='.'||numberLengthSample[numberLengthDummy-1]==',')
    {
        numlenc--;
    }
    numberLengthDummy--;
}
return numlenc;
}

#endif // NUMLEN_H
```

But it gives me 3 errors: 
1) (line 3) macro names must be identifiers
2) (line 7) 'strlen' was not declared in this scope (obviously)
3) (line 5 (when executed from my test .cpp)) initializing argument 1 of 'int numlen(char*)' [-fpermissive]|

I tried to look for an answer, yet with no prevail. Any help would be appreciated :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ you have to `#include` headers instead of `#define` them:

```
#ifndef NUMLEN_H
#define NUMLEN_H
#include <cstring>
```

It's not related to the question, but you should only declare functions inside header file and implement them inside source file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are using #define instead of #include, it should be:

```
#include <cstring>
```